# how to run useEffect only twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is My useEffect is going in Infinite loop, becouse checkimage value is changing becouse the value is assigned in fetch(), so anyone know how to solve it. I want to get varient data with image but I can't get it in first time.
help me if you can

***Thank You***

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch({ pagination }); 
  }, [checkimage]);

  const fetch = async (params = {}) => {
    if (type == 'product') {
      dispatch(await ProductService.getProduct(productId))
        .then((res) => {
          let variantsdatas = getImageArns(res.data.variants);
          getImages(variantsdatas);
          let record = [];         
          record.push(res.data)
          setVarientsData(record)        
        })
        .catch((err) => {});
    } else {
      dispatch(await ProductService.getProducts())
        .then((res) => {
          console.info({ 'res.data': res.data });
          setVarientsData(res.data.products);
          setPagination({
            ...params.pagination,
            total: res.total_count,
          });
        })
        .catch((err) => {});
    }
  };



const getImageArns = (variantsdatas) => {
    const variantImageArns = [];
    variantsdatas.forEach((variant, index) => {
      variant[index] = variant.variantId;
      if (variant.variantImagesListResponseDto.images.length > 0) {
        let variantImageObj = {
          variantId: variant.variantId,
          arnUrl: variant.variantImagesListResponseDto.images[0].docUrl,
        };
        variantImageArns.push(variantImageObj);
      }
    });
    // console.info('id', variantImageArns);
    return variantImageArns;
  };

  const getImages = async (variantsdatas) => {
    const images = [];
    dispatch(await ProductVariantService.getImage(variantsdatas))
      .then((res) => {
        console.info(res.data.fileResponseDtoList);
        let presignedURLs = {};
        res.data.fileResponseDtoList.map(
          (i) => (
            (presignedURLs = {
              variantId: i.variantId,
              arnUrl: i.presignedURL,
            }),
            console.info(presignedURLs),
            images.push(presignedURLs)
          )
        );
        setcheckimage(images);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.info('Get Error District...');
      });
    };




 var img = 'img';
  const setVarientsData = (products) => {
    let varients_array = [];
    if (products.length > 0) {
      products.forEach((product) => { 
        if (product.variants.length > 0) {
          let product_varients = product.variants;          
          product_varients.forEach((varient) => {
           
            for (var f = 0; f < checkimage.length; f++) {        
              if(checkimage[f].variantId == varient.variantId){
                img = checkimage[f].arnUrl;
                f = checkimage.length
              }                            
              else{
                img = 'img2'; 
              }                                           
            } 
            varients_array.push({
              image: img,
              variantId: varient.variantId,
              productVariantName: varient.variantName,
              productName: product.productName,
              brand: '-',
              sellerSku: varient.productVariantCode,
              status: product.status,
              category: product.subCategoryInfo.categoryInfo.categoryName,
              subCategoryName: product.subCategoryInfo.subCategoryName,
              state: '-',
              market: '-',
              mrp: varient.price.amount + ' ' + varient.price.currency,
              sellingPrice: '-',
              manufacturer_product_variant_code:
                varient.manufacturerProductVariantCode,
              product_varient_code: varient.azProductVariantLongCode,
              hsnCode: varient.hsnCode,
            });            
          });
        }
      });
    }
    setVarients(varients_array);
    console.info('varients_array ====>>', {varients_array})
  };
```

I think that if I stop to run blow code getImage function then I can get my result
am I right?

But I tried It too but is also not happening properly.

Answer (score 0):

a quick and dirty fix could be to work with a counter.
and only run the fetch in the useEffect, when counter is 0.
have you tried that?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Its not solving the issue.

Comment: and you really need two rerender?
isn't just one initial rerender enough?
then u just could use empty brackets []